# What is the need of using Override with UITableView methods

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, overriding, swift5

What is the need of using Override with UITableView methods and when to use this. Every time override not used but wherever used why used. Please specify. Thanks.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

}
```

Comment: This is Swift 2 code which doesn't work in Swift 5 anyway. A method must be overridden if it already exists in the class or struct and you want (or need) to change its functionality.

Comment: @vadian this is just the sample code pasted to ask the question. But concern is same that why and when to use override

Comment: @Rob Please confirm my understanding. If i am using UITableView in my UITableViewController does it means i am subclassing it and need to use override there. If using UITableView in simple ViewController then can use table view methods without using override because not subclassing there or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, that’s basically it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60035519/1271826) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you need override qualifier whenever you are implementing a method or property that the base class has implemented. For example, when you implement `viewDidLoad` in a `UIViewController` subclass, you need to specify `override` because you are overriding the `viewDidLoad` method already implemented in `UIViewController`.

For more information about overriding, see [The Swift Programming Language: Inheritance: Overriding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html#ID196).

So in the case of scenes with table views, you will see one of two basic patterns:

1. If you have subclassed `UIViewController` and have added your own `UITableView` to that, you’d have an implementation like:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           ...
       }
   }

   // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

   extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           ...
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   In this scenario, you would:

   - in Interface Builder (IB), you would hook up the outlet to the table view;
   - specify the view controller as the “data source” (and likely the “delegate”, too) for the table view (you can do this either in IB directly, or programmatically in your `viewDidLoad` method); but
   - notice that there is no `override` keyword on the two [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) methods because `UIViewController` hasn’t implemented these methods.

   Note that I defined the conformance to the `UITableViewDataSource` in an extension. (See [The Swift Programming Language: Protocols: Adding Protocol Conformance with an Extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID277).) You don’t have to do that, but it keeps the code in your view controller nicely organized if you declare your protocol conformance in an extension. Not only is it clear and unambiguous, but if you do code folding in Xcode (where you can collapse sections of your code so you can focus on other portions of your code). It’s a good habit to get into.
2. Alternatively, if you’re subclassing `UITableViewController`, then you’d need the `override` declaration on those two data source methods, because you’re overriding those two methods that have already been declared within the base class, `UITableViewController`:

   ```
   class ViewController: UITableViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           ...
       }
   }

   // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

   extension ViewController {
       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           ...
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   Obviously, when using `UITableViewController`:

   - you don’t have to declare the `tableView` outlet or specify the data source or delegate in IB;
   - you don’t specify the `UITableViewDataSource` conformance explicitly (because the base class, `UITableViewController` already conforms to that protocol); but
   - you do have to include the `override` keyword in your implementation of those `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

In terms of when you use one approach instead of the other, it’s a question of what’s present in your UI. If you are OK with the table view as as the root view of your view controller’s scene, then `UITableViewController` is perhaps a tad simpler. But if your view controller’s scene might include other controls where the table view might not occupy the whole scene, then you would want to adopt the `UIViewController` pattern, where you can add however many outlets and controls in your storyboard scene that you might need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are subclassing `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`.

`UITableViewController` conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and provides  implementations of the two required functions, `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` and `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.  You must add the `override` keyword to acknowledge that you are overriding the superclass functions in your `UITableViewController` subclass.

`UIViewController` doesn't conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol - You need to add this conformance yourself either in the class definition or through an extension.  Since you are adding the conformance there are no superclass implementations of the required functions for you to override.